# Choosing Embedded Linux for device

Tags: sqlite, qt, embedded-linux

I am starting to create a QT application with sqlite for a hand held device. My Project Manager asks me to select an operating system (embedded linux) for the device (we are not considering android).

As in Desktop, are there many embedded-Linux distributions for devices? 
If so, Which embedded linux I should consider?

Comment: which is the platform? ARM? x86? ....

Comment: "Which distro?" is really an x86 desktop question. Unless you use a popular board like RaspberryPi or BeagleBoard, then your choices are very limited.  So the typical embedded Linux is custom built from scratch using tools like Buildroot or OpenEmbedded. http://free-electrons.com/doc/buildroot.pdf

Comment: Start with whatever someone else has been able to make run on the board in question, or whatever existing board is closest to it, since that will normally be a lot less work.  Change (if necessary to your own custom setup) if there are reasons that proves unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple choices, but I will suggest the easier and - in my opinion - better two.

- **[Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/)** - is a set of makefiles that lets you create your custom embedded distribution. Can take care of building the Linux
  kernel, the toolchain and a barebox or U-Boot bootloader, too. Easily expandable and
  with a practically zero learning curve. You have a fully working
  system in a matter of hours.
- **[Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/)** - a fully fledged (and complicated) build system. Suggested over Buildroot when you need a LOT of packages/components
  and may need flexibility in expanding the system directly on
  premises. What you can do substantially depends on the "layers" (sets of rules for building things) available: you combine layers together to obtain your system. Has a steep learning curve but is used and directly
  supported by multiple vendors (e.g.: Atmel, TI).

Anyway, unless you have more than good reasons, I strongly suggest the former.

Answer (score 0):

There are several Linux distros to be used with ARM. Maybe you should consider Fedora ARM https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question to answer not knowing more about the project requirements (not just software requirements, but also non-functional ones as well) and capabilities of the platform.

[Angstrom](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org) (based on OpenEmbedded) is another possibility for Linux.

I would challenge the assumption that the operating system must be Linux. Why?  If time-to-market or having commercial support are important,  you might be better off with commercial embedded or RT operations systems such as [VxWorks](http://www.windriver.com/products/vxworks/) or [QNX](http://www.qnx.org.uk).

There are also professionally supported Linux distros such as [Montavista](http://www.mvista.com)

Whilst free linux distros are, well, free,  you are generally on your own and your team's time isn't free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Qt for embedded device , it’s fast and compatible with many hardwares and if your hardware is not supported, porting it to a new hardware is not so hard 
plus it has special rendering system